# Editting a WebPart that is fixed to a PageLayout

Tags: 2013, web-part, search, page-layout

I hope this is fairly simple. I have a refiner and Search Results WebPart that are fixed onto a Page Layout, when I go into edit page I would like to be able to edit the webpart as well. Is there anyway of doing this?

I am using SharePoint 2013

Something like this seems to work but I can't seem to apply it to mine

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone 
            runat="server" 
            AllowPersonalization="false" 
            FrameType="TitleBarOnly" 
            title="<%$Resources:Microsoft.Office.Server.Search,LayoutPageZone_NavigationZone%>" 
            id="NavigationZone" orientation="Vertical" 
            QuickAdd-GroupNames="Search" 
            QuickAdd-ShowListsAndLibraries="false"><ZoneTemplate>
        <spsswc:RefinementScriptWebPart runat="server" SelectedRefinementControlsJson="{&quot;refinerConfigurations&quot;:[{&quot;propertyName&quot;:&quot;FileType&quot;,&quot;displayName&quot;:null,&quot;displayTemplate&quot;:&quot;~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Filters/Filter_Default.js&quot;,&quot;maxNumberRefinementOptions&quot;:21,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Text&quot;,&quot;refinerSpecStringOverride&quot;:null,&quot;useDefaultDateIntervals&quot;:false,&quot;isInherited&quot;:false,&quot;sortBy&quot;:0,&quot;sortOrder&quot;:0,&quot;intervals&quot;:null,&quot;aliases&quot;:null},{&quot;propertyName&quot;:&quot;contentclass&quot;,&quot;displayName&quot;:null,&quot;displayTemplate&quot;:&quot;~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Filters/Filter_Default.js&quot;,&quot;maxNumberRefinementOptions&quot;:10,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Text&quot;,&quot;refinerSpecStringOverride&quot;:null,&quot;useDefaultDateIntervals&quot;:false,&quot;isInherited&quot;:false,&quot;sortBy&quot;:0,&quot;sortOrder&quot;:0,&quot;intervals&quot;:null,&quot;aliases&quot;:null},{&quot;propertyName&quot;:&quot;ContentTypeId&quot;,&quot;displayName&quot;:null,&quot;displayTemplate&quot;:&quot;~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Filters/Filter_Default.js&quot;,&quot;maxNumberRefinementOptions&quot;:15,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Text&quot;,&quot;refinerSpecStringOverride&quot;:null,&quot;useDefaultDateIntervals&quot;:false,&quot;isInherited&quot;:false,&quot;sortBy&quot;:0,&quot;sortOrder&quot;:0,&quot;intervals&quot;:null,&quot;aliases&quot;:null},{&quot;propertyName&quot;:&quot;WebTemplate&quot;,&quot;displayName&quot;:null,&quot;displayTemplate&quot;:&quot;~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Filters/Filter_Default.js&quot;,&quot;maxNumberRefinementOptions&quot;:10,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Text&quot;,&quot;refinerSpecStringOverride&quot;:null,&quot;useDefaultDateIntervals&quot;:false,&quot;isInherited&quot;:false,&quot;sortBy&quot;:0,&quot;sortOrder&quot;:0,&quot;intervals&quot;:null,&quot;aliases&quot;:null},{&quot;propertyName&quot;:&quot;DisplayAuthor&quot;,&quot;displayName&quot;:null,&quot;displayTemplate&quot;:&quot;~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Filters/Filter_Default.js&quot;,&quot;maxNumberRefinementOptions&quot;:9,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Text&quot;,&quot;refinerSpecStringOverride&quot;:null,&quot;useDefaultDateIntervals&quot;:false,&quot;isInherited&quot;:false,&quot;sortBy&quot;:0,&quot;sortOrder&quot;:0,&quot;intervals&quot;:null,&quot;aliases&quot;:null},{&quot;propertyName&quot;:&quot;LastModifiedTime&quot;,&quot;displayName&quot;:null,&quot;displayTemplate&quot;:&quot;~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Filters/Filter_SliderBarGraph.js&quot;,&quot;maxNumberRefinementOptions&quot;:0,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;DateTime&quot;,&quot;refinerSpecStringOverride&quot;:null,&quot;useDefaultDateIntervals&quot;:true,&quot;isInherited&quot;:false,&quot;sortBy&quot;:0,&quot;sortOrder&quot;:0,&quot;intervals&quot;:null,&quot;aliases&quot;:null}]}" UseManagedNavigationRefiners="False" QueryGroupName="Default" StatesJson="{}" ServerIncludeScriptsJson="null" Title="Refinement" FrameType="None" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" Description="This webpart helps the users to refine search results" IsIncluded="True" ZoneID="NavigationZone" PartOrder="2" FrameState="Normal" AllowRemove="True" AllowZoneChange="True" AllowMinimize="True" AllowConnect="True" AllowEdit="True" AllowHide="True" IsVisible="True" DetailLink="" HelpLink="" HelpMode="Modeless" Dir="Default" PartImageSmall="" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." PartImageLarge="" IsIncludedFilter="" ExportControlledProperties="True" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ID="g_92d23ccc_7cfe_4584_a393_df13b4cc9d57" ChromeType="None" ExportMode="All" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{92D23CCC-7CFE-4584-A393-DF13B4CC9D57}" WebPart="true" Height="" Width=""></spsswc:RefinementScriptWebPart>

<spsswc:RefinementScriptWebPart runat="server" SelectedRefinementControlsJson="{&quot;refinerConfigurations&quot;:[{&quot;propertyName&quot;:&quot;FileType&quot;,&quot;displayName&quot;:null,&quot;displayTemplate&quot;:&quot;~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Filters/Filter_Default.js&quot;,&quot;maxNumberRefinementOptions&quot;:21,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Text&quot;,&quot;refinerSpecStringOverride&quot;:null,&quot;useDefaultDateIntervals&quot;:false,&quot;isInherited&quot;:false,&quot;sortBy&quot;:0,&quot;sortOrder&quot;:0,&quot;intervals&quot;:null,&quot;aliases&quot;:null},{&quot;propertyName&quot;:&quot;contentclass&quot;,&quot;displayName&quot;:null,&quot;displayTemplate&quot;:&quot;~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Filters/Filter_Default.js&quot;,&quot;maxNumberRefinementOptions&quot;:10,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Text&quot;,&quot;refinerSpecStringOverride&quot;:null,&quot;useDefaultDateIntervals&quot;:false,&quot;isInherited&quot;:false,&quot;sortBy&quot;:0,&quot;sortOrder&quot;:0,&quot;intervals&quot;:null,&quot;aliases&quot;:null},{&quot;propertyName&quot;:&quot;ContentTypeId&quot;,&quot;displayName&quot;:null,&quot;displayTemplate&quot;:&quot;~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Filters/Filter_Default.js&quot;,&quot;maxNumberRefinementOptions&quot;:15,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Text&quot;,&quot;refinerSpecStringOverride&quot;:null,&quot;useDefaultDateIntervals&quot;:false,&quot;isInherited&quot;:false,&quot;sortBy&quot;:0,&quot;sortOrder&quot;:0,&quot;intervals&quot;:null,&quot;aliases&quot;:null},{&quot;propertyName&quot;:&quot;WebTemplate&quot;,&quot;displayName&quot;:null,&quot;displayTemplate&quot;:&quot;~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Filters/Filter_Default.js&quot;,&quot;maxNumberRefinementOptions&quot;:10,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Text&quot;,&quot;refinerSpecStringOverride&quot;:null,&quot;useDefaultDateIntervals&quot;:false,&quot;isInherited&quot;:false,&quot;sortBy&quot;:0,&quot;sortOrder&quot;:0,&quot;intervals&quot;:null,&quot;aliases&quot;:null},{&quot;propertyName&quot;:&quot;DisplayAuthor&quot;,&quot;displayName&quot;:null,&quot;displayTemplate&quot;:&quot;~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Filters/Filter_Default.js&quot;,&quot;maxNumberRefinementOptions&quot;:9,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Text&quot;,&quot;refinerSpecStringOverride&quot;:null,&quot;useDefaultDateIntervals&quot;:false,&quot;isInherited&quot;:false,&quot;sortBy&quot;:0,&quot;sortOrder&quot;:0,&quot;intervals&quot;:null,&quot;aliases&quot;:null},{&quot;propertyName&quot;:&quot;LastModifiedTime&quot;,&quot;displayName&quot;:null,&quot;displayTemplate&quot;:&quot;~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Filters/Filter_SliderBarGraph.js&quot;,&quot;maxNumberRefinementOptions&quot;:0,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;DateTime&quot;,&quot;refinerSpecStringOverride&quot;:null,&quot;useDefaultDateIntervals&quot;:true,&quot;isInherited&quot;:false,&quot;sortBy&quot;:0,&quot;sortOrder&quot;:0,&quot;intervals&quot;:null,&quot;aliases&quot;:null}]}" UseManagedNavigationRefiners="False" QueryGroupName="Default" StatesJson="{}" ServerIncludeScriptsJson="null" Title="Refinement" FrameType="None" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" Description="This webpart helps the users to refine search results" IsIncluded="True" ZoneID="NavigationZone" PartOrder="4" FrameState="Normal" AllowRemove="True" AllowZoneChange="True" AllowMinimize="True" AllowConnect="True" AllowEdit="True" AllowHide="True" IsVisible="True" DetailLink="" HelpLink="" HelpMode="Modeless" Dir="Default" PartImageSmall="" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." PartImageLarge="" IsIncludedFilter="" ExportControlledProperties="True" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ID="g_4bafcd0f_0197_49f7_950e_c4e1695924f7" ChromeType="None" ExportMode="All" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{4BAFCD0F-0197-49F7-950E-C4E1695924F7}" WebPart="true" Height="" Width=""></spsswc:RefinementScriptWebPart>

<spsswc:RefinementScriptWebPart runat="server" SelectedRefinementControlsJson="{&quot;refinerConfigurations&quot;:[{&quot;propertyName&quot;:&quot;FileType&quot;,&quot;displayName&quot;:null,&quot;displayTemplate&quot;:&quot;~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Filters/Filter_Default.js&quot;,&quot;maxNumberRefinementOptions&quot;:21,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Text&quot;,&quot;refinerSpecStringOverride&quot;:null,&quot;useDefaultDateIntervals&quot;:false,&quot;isInherited&quot;:false,&quot;sortBy&quot;:0,&quot;sortOrder&quot;:0,&quot;intervals&quot;:null,&quot;aliases&quot;:null},{&quot;propertyName&quot;:&quot;contentclass&quot;,&quot;displayName&quot;:null,&quot;displayTemplate&quot;:&quot;~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Filters/Filter_Default.js&quot;,&quot;maxNumberRefinementOptions&quot;:10,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Text&quot;,&quot;refinerSpecStringOverride&quot;:null,&quot;useDefaultDateIntervals&quot;:false,&quot;isInherited&quot;:false,&quot;sortBy&quot;:0,&quot;sortOrder&quot;:0,&quot;intervals&quot;:null,&quot;aliases&quot;:null},{&quot;propertyName&quot;:&quot;ContentTypeId&quot;,&quot;displayName&quot;:null,&quot;displayTemplate&quot;:&quot;~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Filters/Filter_Default.js&quot;,&quot;maxNumberRefinementOptions&quot;:15,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Text&quot;,&quot;refinerSpecStringOverride&quot;:null,&quot;useDefaultDateIntervals&quot;:false,&quot;isInherited&quot;:false,&quot;sortBy&quot;:0,&quot;sortOrder&quot;:0,&quot;intervals&quot;:null,&quot;aliases&quot;:null},{&quot;propertyName&quot;:&quot;WebTemplate&quot;,&quot;displayName&quot;:null,&quot;displayTemplate&quot;:&quot;~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Filters/Filter_Default.js&quot;,&quot;maxNumberRefinementOptions&quot;:10,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Text&quot;,&quot;refinerSpecStringOverride&quot;:null,&quot;useDefaultDateIntervals&quot;:false,&quot;isInherited&quot;:false,&quot;sortBy&quot;:0,&quot;sortOrder&quot;:0,&quot;intervals&quot;:null,&quot;aliases&quot;:null},{&quot;propertyName&quot;:&quot;DisplayAuthor&quot;,&quot;displayName&quot;:null,&quot;displayTemplate&quot;:&quot;~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Filters/Filter_Default.js&quot;,&quot;maxNumberRefinementOptions&quot;:9,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Text&quot;,&quot;refinerSpecStringOverride&quot;:null,&quot;useDefaultDateIntervals&quot;:false,&quot;isInherited&quot;:false,&quot;sortBy&quot;:0,&quot;sortOrder&quot;:0,&quot;intervals&quot;:null,&quot;aliases&quot;:null},{&quot;propertyName&quot;:&quot;LastModifiedTime&quot;,&quot;displayName&quot;:null,&quot;displayTemplate&quot;:&quot;~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Filters/Filter_SliderBarGraph.js&quot;,&quot;maxNumberRefinementOptions&quot;:0,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;DateTime&quot;,&quot;refinerSpecStringOverride&quot;:null,&quot;useDefaultDateIntervals&quot;:true,&quot;isInherited&quot;:false,&quot;sortBy&quot;:0,&quot;sortOrder&quot;:0,&quot;intervals&quot;:null,&quot;aliases&quot;:null}]}" UseManagedNavigationRefiners="False" QueryGroupName="Default" StatesJson="{}" ServerIncludeScriptsJson="null" Title="Refinement" FrameType="None" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" Description="This webpart helps the users to refine search results" IsIncluded="True" ZoneID="NavigationZone" PartOrder="6" FrameState="Normal" AllowRemove="True" AllowZoneChange="True" AllowMinimize="True" AllowConnect="True" AllowEdit="True" AllowHide="True" IsVisible="True" DetailLink="" HelpLink="" HelpMode="Modeless" Dir="Default" PartImageSmall="" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." PartImageLarge="" IsIncludedFilter="" ExportControlledProperties="True" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ID="g_25e00a23_1f6d_4b9a_b996_d4d74fffe5d7" ChromeType="None" ExportMode="All" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{25E00A23-1F6D-4B9A-B996-D4D74FFFE5D7}" WebPart="true" Height="" Width=""></spsswc:RefinementScriptWebPart>

<spsswc:RefinementScriptWebPart runat="server" SelectedRefinementControlsJson="{&quot;refinerConfigurations&quot;:[{&quot;propertyName&quot;:&quot;FileType&quot;,&quot;displayName&quot;:null,&quot;displayTemplate&quot;:&quot;~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Filters/Filter_Default.js&quot;,&quot;maxNumberRefinementOptions&quot;:21,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Text&quot;,&quot;refinerSpecStringOverride&quot;:null,&quot;useDefaultDateIntervals&quot;:false,&quot;isInherited&quot;:false,&quot;sortBy&quot;:0,&quot;sortOrder&quot;:0,&quot;intervals&quot;:null,&quot;aliases&quot;:null},{&quot;propertyName&quot;:&quot;contentclass&quot;,&quot;displayName&quot;:null,&quot;displayTemplate&quot;:&quot;~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Filters/Filter_Default.js&quot;,&quot;maxNumberRefinementOptions&quot;:10,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Text&quot;,&quot;refinerSpecStringOverride&quot;:null,&quot;useDefaultDateIntervals&quot;:false,&quot;isInherited&quot;:false,&quot;sortBy&quot;:0,&quot;sortOrder&quot;:0,&quot;intervals&quot;:null,&quot;aliases&quot;:null},{&quot;propertyName&quot;:&quot;ContentTypeId&quot;,&quot;displayName&quot;:null,&quot;displayTemplate&quot;:&quot;~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Filters/Filter_Default.js&quot;,&quot;maxNumberRefinementOptions&quot;:15,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Text&quot;,&quot;refinerSpecStringOverride&quot;:null,&quot;useDefaultDateIntervals&quot;:false,&quot;isInherited&quot;:false,&quot;sortBy&quot;:0,&quot;sortOrder&quot;:0,&quot;intervals&quot;:null,&quot;aliases&quot;:null},{&quot;propertyName&quot;:&quot;WebTemplate&quot;,&quot;displayName&quot;:null,&quot;displayTemplate&quot;:&quot;~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Filters/Filter_Default.js&quot;,&quot;maxNumberRefinementOptions&quot;:10,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Text&quot;,&quot;refinerSpecStringOverride&quot;:null,&quot;useDefaultDateIntervals&quot;:false,&quot;isInherited&quot;:false,&quot;sortBy&quot;:0,&quot;sortOrder&quot;:0,&quot;intervals&quot;:null,&quot;aliases&quot;:null},{&quot;propertyName&quot;:&quot;DisplayAuthor&quot;,&quot;displayName&quot;:null,&quot;displayTemplate&quot;:&quot;~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Filters/Filter_Default.js&quot;,&quot;maxNumberRefinementOptions&quot;:9,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;Text&quot;,&quot;refinerSpecStringOverride&quot;:null,&quot;useDefaultDateIntervals&quot;:false,&quot;isInherited&quot;:false,&quot;sortBy&quot;:0,&quot;sortOrder&quot;:0,&quot;intervals&quot;:null,&quot;aliases&quot;:null},{&quot;propertyName&quot;:&quot;LastModifiedTime&quot;,&quot;displayName&quot;:null,&quot;displayTemplate&quot;:&quot;~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Filters/Filter_SliderBarGraph.js&quot;,&quot;maxNumberRefinementOptions&quot;:0,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;DateTime&quot;,&quot;refinerSpecStringOverride&quot;:null,&quot;useDefaultDateIntervals&quot;:true,&quot;isInherited&quot;:false,&quot;sortBy&quot;:0,&quot;sortOrder&quot;:0,&quot;intervals&quot;:null,&quot;aliases&quot;:null}]}" UseManagedNavigationRefiners="False" QueryGroupName="Default" StatesJson="{}" ServerIncludeScriptsJson="null" Title="Refinement" FrameType="None" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" Description="This webpart helps the users to refine search results" IsIncluded="True" ZoneID="NavigationZone" PartOrder="8" FrameState="Normal" AllowRemove="True" AllowZoneChange="True" AllowMinimize="True" AllowConnect="True" AllowEdit="True" AllowHide="True" IsVisible="True" DetailLink="" HelpLink="" HelpMode="Modeless" Dir="Default" PartImageSmall="" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." PartImageLarge="" IsIncludedFilter="" ExportControlledProperties="True" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ID="g_d4ec6380_3d80_4057_b254_730f100b5740" ChromeType="None" ExportMode="All" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{D4EC6380-3D80-4057-B254-730F100B5740}" WebPart="true" Height="" Width=""></spsswc:RefinementScriptWebPart>

        </ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>&nbsp;
```

Comment: First create a webpart zone. And make sure that works. Then try to add the search webpart.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change your approach. Create webpart zone in the place of Search WebParts. Then while creating the page choose this new layout. Then edit page and add the Search WebParts.

If you have made customizations to the Search WebPart which you want to reuse, then "Export" the webpart and then upload it to the webpart gallery as a new webpart.

The problem with your approach is, contents that are fixed to the page layout can't be modified by editing a page. For editing fixed content on page layout require to edit the page layout itself.